# html labels within a li tag

Tags: html

I am trying layout labels with in li tag divided into3 columns, it is working perfectly fine except when there are multiple line for any field, horizontal alignment is getting disturbed. I tried all possible ways but was not able to find out the solution

Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/pHHhz/2

Can someone crack this..

Answer (score 2):

`label` tags are not meant for what you're using them for. They're meant for describe form `input`-type elements.

It looks like you need to use a `table` here rather than unordered lists. Don't be afraid of tables; if you need to display tabular data (which this looks like) then use them!